# Java image comparing class - add offset

Tags: java, image, compare

I found this Java class online and have been using it to compare images. However I want to add an offset to it. So for example, if the 2 images are 99% or 98% similar, I want it to return true.

```
public int compareImage(File fileA, File fileB) {
    try {
        // take buffer data from botm image files //
        BufferedImage biA = ImageIO.read(fileA);
        DataBuffer dbA = biA.getData().getDataBuffer();
        int sizeA = dbA.getSize();
        BufferedImage biB = ImageIO.read(fileB);
        DataBuffer dbB = biB.getData().getDataBuffer();
        int sizeB = dbB.getSize();
        // compare data-buffer objects //
        if (sizeA == sizeB) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
                if (dbA.getElem(i) != dbB.getElem(i)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to compare image files ...");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: first you have to define "similar"

Comment: that's a category, not a definition

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but I use this for comparing screenshots in a testing framework.

Comment: Should two images be similar if one is brighter than the other? Shifted left? Rotated? Enlarged? Colorized?  There are many ways to compare images; there is no such thing as "best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if they are 99% or 98% similar, you have to compare all the pixels, instead of returning false at the first instance of `dbA.getElem(i) != dbB.getElem(i)`

Try a counter:

```
int total = 0;
int is_silimar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
            total++;
            if (dbA.getElem(i) == dbB.getElem(i)) { //change it to ==
                is_similar ++;
            }
        }

 //don't return anything yet
```

Then, you can `return true` when `is_similar/total` is 98% or 99%

Edit: change sizeA to min(sizeA, sizeB) if you want to test cases when the image sizes are different as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches for image similarities, some of them requiring advanced AI algorithms. This Wikipedia [post](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images) offers a pixel by pixel colour-distance image comparison (but it works for equal-sized images only). I am just copy pasting the Java implementation from the above link.

*Note that if you wanted absolute pixel equality (and not colour distance on a single pixel) you should just keep a counter with different pixels and no distance checking would be required.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;


    public class ImgDiffPercent
    {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        BufferedImage img1 = null;
        BufferedImage img2 = null;
        try {
          URL url1 = new URL("http://rosettacode.org/mw/images/3/3c/Lenna50.jpg");
          URL url2 = new URL("http://rosettacode.org/mw/images/b/b6/Lenna100.jpg");
          img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
          img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int width1 = img1.getWidth(null);
        int width2 = img2.getWidth(null);
        int height1 = img1.getHeight(null);
        int height2 = img2.getHeight(null);
        if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) {
          System.err.println("Error: Images dimensions mismatch");
          System.exit(1);
        }
        long diff = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height1; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
            int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(x, y);
            int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(x, y);
            int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
            int b1 = (rgb1      ) & 0xff;
            int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
            int b2 = (rgb2      ) & 0xff;
            diff += Math.abs(r1 - r2);
            diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
            diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);
          }
        }
        double n = width1 * height1 * 3;
        double p = diff / n / 255.0;
        System.out.println("diff percent: " + (p * 100.0));
      }
    }
```